# Login with Twitter for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter

I'm searching for some docs or examples on Codeigniter and logging in with Twitter. I found some Facebook Connect tutorial in codeigniter (which looks dead easy) but not much on Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi try this oauth library will help you to solve your problem https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-oauth2

Comment: I have tried with this showing the following error "Message: include_once(Provider/Twitter.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory"... i think the twitter file is missing in Provider folder